# What is the current status of EU payments to Poland (2022-11)?

Tags: european-union, poland, funding

During a discussion with Polish acquaintances about the current situation in Poland, the topic of EU payments was raised for a moment. The core of the discussion was about the war in Ukraine and I tried to get some information about that afterwards. It isn't very clear, though.

It looks like some money intended for Poland is blocked until some internal law is aligned with the one in the EU (the reason does not matter to my question).

Per the EU budget, Poland is a net debtor of the EU (it receives more than it contributes). Let's call this expected credit `BudgetMoneyYTD` (about 6 B€ YTD). There is some money left until the end of the year `BudgetMoneyRemaining` (total net income for Poland for the year: `BudgetMoneyYTD` + `BudgetMoneyRemaining`)

Following COVID, EU countries were to receive (or already received) some recovery money, let's call it `CovidMoney`. It seems that this is what is currently blocked (about 35 B€).

Finally, there is some other recovery money that seems to be on the table (and will also be blocked if the laws are not in place like before) - I think they were called "Regional Help", amounting to 75 B€. let's call it `RegionalMoney`.

**My question: what is the actual list of funds that are being paid to Poland today (2022-11),  and which ones are denied until the condition is fulfilled?**

Feel free to add some other funds if I missed something (whether they are blocked or not)